# Javascript equivalent of a dropdown combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm looking for an open source javascript / css widget that will display choices in a menu list below the edit field or let me type in my own text. Requirements:

- I'm using contenteditable `<div>` elements.
- The user should be able to select from the suggested options or type in their own text.
- I'll be populating the list of suggestions with items that don't necessarily match anything the user is typing. No Google-style autosuggestion filtering, just show the list of options I give.
- It's going in a Cordova (HTML5 / mobile) app; the solution needs to be cross-browser.
- I'd rather not have to import an entire UI library for the widget; bonus points if the widget is standalone. :-)

I've come across a few options, but each of them needs to be hacked a bit:

- [bootstrap-tagautocomplete](https://sandglaz.github.io/bootstrap-tagautocomplete/). This requires the user to hit the @ sign for the list to display.
- [jQuery.typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js). The nicest looking UI of the bunch, but [it doesn't directly work with contenteditable divs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/235).
- [jquery.autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Looks promising. It's got other dependencies on Jquery UI widgets, and needs some [tweaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324822/autocomplete-with-contenteditable-div-instead-of-textarea-doesnt-seem-to-work) to get it to work with contenteditable divs.

Has anyone come across a library that's already made for contenteditable divs?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it meets all your requirements, but [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) may be worth investigating.

Comment: Thanks Teun! I poked around a bit with Select2, and it looks like it's more geared towards `<select>` elements. I'll probably end up going with Typeahead, as I was able to get it working with `contenteditable` divs. Here's the Gist: https://gist.github.com/eb1/39ed78cf52c6053fcb73